# Spring issues after changing resource to consuming MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I recently changed the following jersey resource by adding the following @Consumes annotation to accept an image file.

```
    @POST
    @PermitAll
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response addImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
        imageService.addImage(uploadedInputStream);
        return Response.ok(200).build();
    }
```

I also added the following parameter to my application initialization

```
registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                "org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
```

Now several random unit tests are failing for the following reason:

```
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response package.webservice.resource.ImageResource.addImage(java.io.InputStream) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class package.webservice.resource.ImageResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@5a515e5d]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response package.webservice.resource.ImageResource.addImage(java.io.InputStream), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
```

is there something that I am missing?

EDIT: adding full registration:

```
registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setName("JerseyFilter");
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    // Set the Jersey filter mapping and context path
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.servlet.filter.contextPath", "/");
    // Load the common package and application package
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
            "com.vanguard.jaxrs.feature;package.webservice.resource");
    // Enable javax security annotations on resources
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature");
    // Enable media type mappings on the URI such as .xml and .json
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.mediaTypeMappings",
            "xml:application/xml, json:application/json");
    // Enable Java bean validation integration
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.servers", "true");
    // Enable fall through to Spring MVC (allows forward to static content
    // if no jersey endpoint found)
    registration.addInitParameter("jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404", "true");
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a specific reason you are using your own `XxxRegistrationBean` instead of just using the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot?

Comment: @peeskillet I am registering a bunch of other stuff as well and its just how I was taught.

Comment: But this can all be done in a `ResourceConfig` subclass annotated with `@Component`. You get the benefit of auto-configuration from Spring Boot. Can you show the complete registration, and any other configuration related to Jersey

Comment: @peeskillet I am using the Spring Boot auto configuration for DataSource and DataSourceTransactionManager btw. If you look above I added the other registration params

Comment: Yeah I don't know. You'd normally see that error when you haven't configured the `MutliPartFeature`, but it looks like you have. I just thought maybe the registration you're using isn't even the one really being used. That's the only thing I could think. That's why I asked

Comment: @peeskillet well thanks anyways, you have me re-thinking the reasoning behind my configuration at least  =]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with my lack of experience configuring JerseyTest. I had to use `.register(MultiPartFeature.class);` on my ResourceConfig when configuring JerseyTest. Doh!